# Traditional Ira Scam Question

Tags: united-states, ira, scams

Have you ever heard of a situation where a potential scammer asks you to open a checking and Traditional ira with the goal transferring money to you anonymously?  The protection of their identity is the reasoning.. high profile individual...

Comment: Too little detail to give a definite answer, but if this involves giving the person the account login/password or transferring some of the money (or goods purchased with the money) to someone else, it's definitely a scam.

Comment: And why would they ask you to do this, rather than a trusted accredited financial advisor or accountant? Of course it’s a scam.

Answer (score 6):

Protection of *their* identity is definitely the reason for doing it.  That way when the police start investigating a bank account that is being used for money laundering or fraud, it will be *your* name that is on the bank account, and not *theirs*.